# Available branch name vars in merge

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to do a config command for merging branches. I see there are some vars available like $BASE $LOCAL AND $REMOTE
These vars contain the name of the file followed by the base, local, remote string.

Are there any variables that contain the name of the branches for these 3?

Comment: Where do you see these variables? Can you give an example?

Comment: I incorporate this into .gitconfig file `cmd = \"C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe\" --title1=\"\"$LOCAL\" = Current branch\" --title2=\"\"$BASE\" = Common ancestor\" --title3=\"\"$REMOTE\" = Merging branch\" /m /r=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"`

Comment: It think those variables are probably defined earlier in the file, or read from the environment; they are not recognized by `git` directly. (Did you copy this code from somewhere else?)

Comment: this is the code that i use in my .gitconfig file and works properly. These vars are not defined inside this file. Don't know if they are or not defined outside and if it so, they were not defined by me and are defined by default in Win version of git.